# How to best juggle between child and parent objects

Tags: c#, object, inheritance

I am going to have a very large database of objects loaded into memory that contain a string (path) and a UInt (index number). For a smaller selection of these at any given time I need to also have many more members for things like extension, filesize, date modified, created and taken, resolution, length and possibly even a bitmap thumbnail. Lots of stuff that I don't want space reserved for in memory because most of it won't be used at any given time.

So with my code, I would input a tag string into a function and it would return a List<> of these file objects. But I then need them to have all of these additional members to load data into.

The only way I know how to handle this is to return that list of the parent objects, create a new list of child objects and copy the data over. Is there a cleaner way of handling this situation?

Comment: What is the parent and child objects? Are the child objects the objects with the additional properties? Copying which data over from what?

Comment: Now what you could do due to c# polymorphism is have a `List<Parent> ` and then do a `foreach(Parent item in list){ if(item is Child) { // do child stuff } `. However, if you instantiated items as Child then all properties will be loaded anyway. so you'd do this to make the code more legible and flexible, but  you can't solve the runtime memory pressure that way.

Comment: The parent just has filepath and index, the child would have everything else. I mean copying data from my retrieved list of parent objects then copying the filepath and index into a new list of child objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use composition instead of inheritance - have an extra property of what's currently your base class for "extended properties"... then just populate that property lazily:

```
public class FileInfo // Or whatever
{
    public string Path { get { ... } };
    public uint Index { get { ... } };
    public ExtendedFileInfo ExtendedFileInfo { get { ... } }
}

public class ExtendedFileInfo
{
    public long Size { get { ... } }
    ...
}
```

You could either *implicitly* load the `ExtendedFileInfo` when the property was requested, or just add a method to populate it explicitly, so that `ExtendedFileInfo` would return a null reference if it wasn't populated yet.

Comment: this is one very neat solution!

Comment: I see... Is this, in your opinion, a better idea than just making a new list of child objects, or just an example of a different way to do it?

Comment: @Stoopkid: Well, there are pros and cons of each approach. This way allows anyone who already *has* a reference to the `FileInfo` to keep it rather than being told about the new extended one.